# LightInject doesn't resolve inherited generic types

Tags: c#, generics, mediator, light-inject, mediatr

I'm trying to use LightInject and MediatR to build generic request handlers. Basically, I have types like the following:

```
public class SomeType { }
public class InheritedType : SomeType { }
public class Handler : IAsyncRequestHandler<SomeType, SomeResponseType> { }
```

And I have registered my `Handler` type into my LightInject container like so:

```
registry.RegisterAssembly(typeof(SomeType).Assembly, (s, type) =>
            !s.IsClass && type.IsAssignableToGenericType(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler<,>)
            );
```

However, when I try and call in to my mediator for an implementation of `IAsyncRequestHandler<InheritedType,SomeResponseType>`, it fails. I would have expected to get my registered `Handler` since `InheritedType` implements `SomeType`.

Am I doing something wrong here, or is there any way in LightInject to achieve the behaviour I've described above?

---

Let me know if it's not clear and I can try and provide more info. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Handler class closes both generic arguments and cannot be changed later.
Just try manually to create a new instance of the Handler class and you will see that there is no way to specify the generic arguments because they are closed.

Change your code to this.

```
public class Handler<T, SomeResponseType> : IAsyncRequestHandler<T, SomeResponseType> where T:IAsyncRequest<SomeResponseType>
{
    public Task<SomeResponseType> Handle(T message)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Register and resolve like this

```
var container = new ServiceContainer();            
container.Register(typeof(IAsyncRequestHandler<,>), typeof(Handler<,>));
var instance = container.GetInstance<IAsyncRequestHandler<InheritedType, SomeResponseType>>();
```

Comment: I ended up working aroudn it a different way to avoid the extra layer of generics, but good info to know, thanks! And thanks for the awsome library!